# How to print all the palindromic numbers?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, primes, palindrome

new to Java here. I finished finding all the prime number up until a certain number (the user gives) but im finding palindromic numbe now. I've tried some ways but all seem to mess up the prime portion.

Comment: I would split your prime and palindromic check into two methods (single responsibilty principle: do one thing and do it well). Then, in your loop first check if it is prime and if it is, check if it is a palindromic number. This should also be more efficient because you reduce the number of palindromic checks (or number of prime checks, depending on the order in which you perform the checks. palindromic check is probably even cheaper than testing for primes, so I would test that first)

Comment: You might want to think about using `String[] digits = number.toString().split("")`

Comment: An easy way to check a palindrome would be to turn the Integer into a String and then use the [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class to reverse the String. Then you can either convert it back to an Integer using the `Integer.parseInt()` method and check if they're equal, or use a `.equals()` call using the original String and the reverse version.

Comment: Apart from 2 and 5, every prime number must end in 1, 3, 7 or 9.  You can eliminate a lot of multi-digit numbers by looking at the most significant digit.

Answer (score 0):

Checking palindrome is not difficult. It is easy than finding if the number is prime or not. You can use the following logic to check if the prime number is palindrome or not.

```
 boolean isPalindrome(int num) {
    int reversed = 0, remainder, original;
    original = num;
    while (num != 0) {
        remainder = num % 10;
        reversed = reversed * 10 + remainder;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return original == reversed;
}
```

As you only want to use one method this logic can be put inside your isPalin method in place of returning true. If the number is prime you can further check if it is palindromic or not.

```
static boolean isPalin(int primenumcheck) {
    int leftover;
    for (int i = 2; i <= primenumcheck / 2; i++) {
        leftover = primenumcheck % i;
        //if remainder is 0 than numberToCheckber is not prime and break 
   loop. Elese continue loop
        if (leftover == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // logic to check Palindromic prime
    int reversed = 0, remainder, original;
    original = primenumcheck;
    while (primenumcheck != 0) {
        remainder = primenumcheck % 10;
        reversed = reversed * 10 + remainder;
        primenumcheck /= 10;
    }
    return original == reversed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like there are three methods

(1) Convert the number to a string and then have a library call reverse it.  (Slow)

(2) Use some loop over the number and mod 10 math to make a result which you then check for equality with the input.  (Fast)

(3) If you have a list of all primes less than N, write a palindrome *generator* to make all the palindromic numbers less than N, and then compare the lists.   (Allegedly very fast)

(NB: use a set instead of a list, particularly one with a fast lookup to tell you whether a value exists in the set)

---

For the math version, this is easy (assuming base 10)

Take the input number i and make a copy n.
Create an output number o.

[loop]

- Let x = n mod 10
- Divide n by 10.
- Multiply o by ten
- Add x to o
- Repeat until n is zero.

[end loop]

if i == o then it is palindromic